# How do I set an environment variable at build time on a VSO Hosted Build Controller?

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, orleans

How can I set an environmental variable on a VSO Hosted Build Controller at build time? An ideal solution would be using MSBuild arguments.

Scenario **(not necessary to know)**: I am trying to get an Orleans based Azure Hosted Cloud Service to build and deploy using a VSO Hosted Build Controller. Currently I am hosting my own build controller using TFS however we would like to use the VSO hosted build controller. In order for this to work I have to set the Orleans Environmental Variable to a path within my project on the VSO Hosted Build Controller at build time. We are using a continuous deployment model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSBuild Arg is

/p: EnvVarName  = PathAsAString

It can be the full path(p:OrleansSDK="C:\a\scr\Main\Lib") 
or the relative path(/p:OrleansSDK="..\..\Lib"), 
depending on the build process template it might be able to include existing variables (p:OrleansSDK="$(SourcesDir)\Lib").